# In the Here iOS SDK, how can I make an NMAMapMarker show a callout when tapped?

Tags: ios, here-api

I'm building an iOS app that includes Here map & search features, and I'm currently using the "starter" SDK. Currently, when the app performs a search, an NMAMapMarker is created for each search result. I'd like the map display some kind of callout or information box when the user taps on a MapMarker (like what happens when you tap a pin in Apple Maps), but I can't figure out if this feature is included in the SDK.

I know there's a didSelectObject delegate method, but do I have to create a custom view and manually present it? I also noticed that the "Premium" SDK includes an NMAMapOverlay. Is this a better option for displaying info boxes when being tapped? And finally, I noticed in the inheritance diagram of NMAView (https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/interfacenmaviewobject.html) there's an NMALabledMapMarker, but I can't find anything else about it in the API reference. Would this be a good way to show some basic information about a place on a MapMarker? What's the best way to show basic info about a place on a Here map?

Comment: Refer to my answer at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003683/add-an-nmamapoverlay-to-the-map/36400858#36400858

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NMAMapOverlay is the only option right now. This functionality is only provided within the HERE SDK for iOS Premium.

Answer (score 2):

You have a right start.

I suppose you have an array of coordinates which you add as **NMAMapMarkers** on the **NMAMapView**.

So basically every **NMAMapMarker** has it's own **coordinates** from where you can distinguish it from others.

After you conform to **NMAMapViewDelegate**, use this method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: NMAMapView, didSelect objects: [NMAViewObject]) {
  for object in objects {
     // Search for NMAMapMarkers only
     if object is NMAMapMarker {
          // Get your map marker as follow
          let mapMarker = object as! NMAMapMarker
          // Check if you found your map marker by checking coordinates
          // Show desired information with your custom method
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Notice: **NMAMapOverlay** doesn't have any tap detect method which is provided be Here Maps SDK. You have to implement it on your own. Since **NMAMapOverlay** inherits from Apple's **UIView** it allows you to do that.

It's yours to choose between them, based on your needs.

**I would say, go with NMAMapMarker**

Answer (score 1):

Currently, NMAMapOverlay is the only option to display custom view in place of NMAMapMarkers.

NMAMapOverlay* overlaySubview  = [NMAMapOverlay mapOverlayWithSubview:customView geoCoordinates:place.position];

[self.mapView addMapOverlay:overlaySubview];