# Add an NMAMapOverlay to the Map

Tags: here-api

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272385/in-the-here-ios-sdk-how-can-i-make-an-nmamapmarker-show-a-callout-when-tapped/31425295#31425295) was answered saying that NMAMapOverlay is the thing to use for a callout when a user taps a marker.

The SDK documentations says

> The NMAMapOverlay class represents a special type of map object that
>   does not inherit from the NMAMapObject base class. Instead, it
>   inherits from the UIView class of Apple’s UIKit framework.

Since it is a UIView, you cannot call the `addMapObject` of `NMAMapView`.

I cannot find anywhere in the documentation where it says how to add an NMAMapOverlay to the map. Nor is NMAMapOverlay used in the SDKDemo app.

So my question is, how do you add an NMAMapOverlay to the Map?

Comment: Ah! NMAPMapOverlay has a method: addMapOverlay. Once I get the geoCoordinates correct, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code, Modify annotView as per your requirement. Make sure that you have premium plan enabled. It will not work with basic plan.

```
UIView *annotView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 20)];
annotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
NMAMapOverlay *overlay = [[NMAMapOverlay alloc] initWithSubview:annotView];
overlay.coordinates = //your location's NMAGeoCoordinates
[self.mapView addMapOverlay:overlay];
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, as per my comment to the question above, use the addMapOverlay method

Comment: It seems that in the iOS 12.0 with the new framework heremap, the overlay is not at the good place... This seems working, but not placing the overlay exactly where it has to be.

Comment: I think this is because of the self.mapView.tilt = 45; it seems it is not the same working than before